# Opening URLs with user input in CMD Batch File

Tags: batch-file, user-input

I'm a Static Web Dev. & I Don't know much about CMD & Batch Files.
But I need to make a batch file that does this:It first prompts user to enter a specific word & there are some links that have URL & a some kind of name. then if user's input matches one of the link's names, The URL opens in a browser (the default one). I think it is like this with HTML+JS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function input(){
        var stackoverflow = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
        if (val = stackoverflow){
            window.open(stackoverflow);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input" onKeyUp="input()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

but there should be more options & I think it should be done with START command.
Any help is appreciated.THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a simple menu,

```
:: turn off "verbose" command writeback.
@echo off

:: write a simple list of options to console,
:main
echo Options;
echo 1 : StackOverflow
echo 2 : Google
echo 3 : Youtube
echo 4 : This question

:: Prompt for input,
set /p "strMenu=Enter desired URL number:"

:: Compare input through if commands,
:: `if not defined strMenu goto :menu` can be used here if prefered.
if "%strMenu%" equ "1" start "" "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
if "%strMenu%" equ "2" start "" "https://www.Google.com"
if "%strMenu%" equ "3" start "" "https://www.youtube.com"
if "%strMenu%" equ "4" start "" "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945614/opening-urls-with-user-input-in-cmd-batch-file"

exit
```

Note the start command will use the default assigned browser, but this can be set with something like;

`start "" "chrome" "URL"`

Numbers are used for laziness in having to type more than 1 character before hitting enter.